# Get a specific line from object (php)

Tags: php, arrays, object, hyperlink

i get some URLS from HTML site by using

```
foreach($html->find('source') as $video)                   
    if($video->type =='video/mp4')  {

        echo $video->src. '<br>';
```

my output looks like :

```
http://video.csfd.cz/321/321909/130228151/360.mp4
http://video.csfd.cz/321/321909/130228151/720.mp4
http://video.csfd.cz/321/321909/99476124/360.mp4
http://video.csfd.cz/321/321909/99476124/720.mp4
http://video.csfd.cz/321/321909/99476124/1080.mp4
```

and i have just no idea how to get just one of this links, i dont know much about objects so it looks pretty impossible for me to solve this problem.

What i try:
I was thinking about converting object to array and work with it, which sound pretty easy, problem is that if i use :

```
$pole = (array)$video;
 echo "$pole[0]";
```

it says:

```
http://video.csfd.cz/321/321909/130228151/360.mp4

Notice: Undefined offset: 0 in C:\xampp\htdocs\xampp\ocul\subor.php on line 61
http://video.csfd.cz/321/321909/130228151/720.mp4

Notice: Undefined offset: 0 in C:\xampp\htdocs\xampp\ocul\subor.php on line 61
http://video.csfd.cz/321/321909/99476124/360.mp4

Notice: Undefined offset: 0 in C:\xampp\htdocs\xampp\ocul\subor.php on line 61
http://video.csfd.cz/321/321909/99476124/720.mp4

Notice: Undefined offset: 0 in C:\xampp\htdocs\xampp\ocul\subor.php on line 61
http://video.csfd.cz/321/321909/99476124/1080.mp4

Notice: Undefined offset: 0 in C:\xampp\htdocs\xampp\ocul\subor.php on line 61
```

if i use print_r the output is like tons of code , atleast for 1-2x A4 page, soemthing really crazy

So is there a way how to get one specific line from this (prefer to let me chose which one) , or some way to convert this output to array or anything like that?

Comment: cant you just http://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.break.php the loop?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is a bad idea to convert objects into arrays. You could basicly store the links in an array while looping. Try this :

```
$links = array();
foreach ($html->find('source') as $video) {               
    if ($video->type == 'video/mp4')  {
        array_push($links, $video->src);
    }
}
```

And then just use the `$links` array however you want :

```
echo $links[0];
```